# How to detect apple computers using user-agent?

Tags: user-agent

How to detect apple computers using user-agent ?
Safari may be run in windows too

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look for Macintosh in User-Agent, trying this with my Mac browsers:

- Your User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2`
- Your User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0`
- Your User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.27 Safari/536.11`

While safari for Windows has "Windows" instead of Macintosh:

- `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; sv-SE) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.3 Safari/533.19.4`

Answer (score 0):

The user-agent part of http response (page response) and gives you details about the operating system as well. I checked mine and it gives

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/12.0

for windows and mozilla